# HTML 5 - Correct way of using <time> tag

Tags: html, datetime, time

I want to display a date-time using the HTML 5 `<time>` tag, in Dutch (NL) format `dd-mm-yyyy H:i`. But the HTML 5 time tag requires `yyyy-mm-dd H:i`.

So, my code is `<time datetime="2016-11-19 22:45">19-11-2016 22:45 (dd-mm-yyyy H:i)</time>`.

At least W3 validator doesn't give any errors, but is this code still valid for Dutch people and valid for search engines as well?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 1):

The `<time>` tag defines a **human-readable** date/time.

This element can also be used to encode dates and times in a **machine-readable** way so that user agents can offer to add birthday reminders or scheduled events to the user's calendar, and search engines can produce smarter search results. Example usage:

```
 Soon will be <time datetime="2008-12-24 20:00">Christmas Eve day</time>
```

Keep in mind that this is supported on `IE 9+`, `Safari 5.0+`. Note that the `time` element **does not render** as anything special in any of the major browsers.

Comment: Not exactly the answer to my question but thanks for the information!